# Client Error: Remaining data too small for BSON object

Tags: java, mongodb

Java app is connecting to mongo and receives sometimes an error:
Assertion: 10304:Client Error: Remaining data too small for BSON object

Mongo is 3.0.7.
mongo-java-driver is 3.2.2

Comment: Have you already fixed that? I'm with the same problem (but I'm using Node.js) :/